# Are all functions with Lipschitz continuous gradient also strongly convex?

Tags: real-analysis, convex-analysis, lipschitz-functions, smooth-functions

I am sorry for asking probably well known question. But I am so confused.

> Are all functions, say $f$, with Lipschitz continuous gradient, say, $\nabla f$ is $L$-Lipschitz,  also strongly convex function $f$?

Comment: Lipschitz-continuity doesn't say anything about the sign of the curvature, look for example at $f: \mathbb R \to \mathbb R : x \mapsto - x^2$.

Comment: Note that Lipschitz is a regularity condition, whereas convexity is a geometric condition. Hence even if you were to assume that a function is smooth, it need not be convex (draw a squiggly line in the plane).

Comment: @Targon Thank you for your comment.

There is some relationship with the duality? but I am not able to connect the dots yet.

Comment: @Iwassuspendedfortalking Thank you for your comment. 
There is some relationship with the duality? but I am not able to connect the dots yet. or I am just confusing myself...

Comment: @learning Sine is smooth but not convex.

Comment: @postmortes $f(t) = t^2$ is convex, isn't it? Do you mean not "strongly" convex?

Comment: Sorry, my mistake, I misread it as you wanting a Lipschitz $f$, not convex.  I'll delete. Though, $f(t)=-t^2$ is not convex but has Lipschitz derivative.

Comment: @postmortes No problems. Thank you. It makes sense.